# Testing REST calls and connection

Tags: android, mocking, functional-testing, android-testing

I want to use `Functional testing` to test my application, but I don't really understand how can I test in my application.
It has only one button that start the method connect(). This method calls sequentially 4 HTTP call, everyone with the result of the previous as body (more or less).
So, i have `asynctask` to do `POST` request and in `postExtecute` I call the next `POST`.

connect -> Call `A` -> Call `B` with some `A` data like auth token -> Call `C` with `B` data -> call `D` with `C` data.

how can I test It? I don't have the server UP, so basically I use something to mock HTTP and check if I have `D`'s data into `sharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MockServer](http://mock-server.com). It allows you to specify the responses and verify the requests.